# Error when complie chaincode

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I followed the tutorial [Simple Asset Chaincode](http://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chaincode4ade.html#simple-asset-chaincode) of Hyperledger Fabric Docs, but

1. when I execute the code  `go get -u --tags nopkcs11
   github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim`, I got the
   following error message:

   > package github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/chaincode/shim: cannot download, http ://gerrit.hyperledger.org/r/fabric uses insecure
   >   protocol

   How can I solve it? (I have successfully implemented the network
   using Docker Quickstart Terminal tool on Windows 7)
2. If I ignore the command in question 1, I still can successful build the chaincode when I execute `go build --tags nopkcs11`. Does it mean that the command in question 1 is ignorable?

Comment: The command works for me on windows and on linux.
What is your golang version?

Comment: My golang version is go1.9 windows/amd64.

Answer (score 2):

> If I ignore the command in question 1, I still can successful build
>   the chaincode when I execute go build --tags nopkcs11. Does it mean
>   that the command in question 1 is ignorable?

No, it just means you probably have this package in your GOPATH already, or that your chaincode does't require to include the shim package in the binary.

Comment: Thank you~~~  Do you know how can I solve the problem in question 1?

Comment: are you behind a proxy or something?

Comment: Maybe, I deployed the test environment in the company. Is it a problem?:(

Comment: Suggest you use wireshark or something similar to track what happens - maybe you're redirected or something.